# Magento 2 recaptcha issues sometimes

Tags: forms, magento2, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

for some customers,they cannot register has users in our website because of the Google invisible recaptcha v3 failing some times.

Getting the "Something went wrong with reCAPTCHA. Please contact the store owner."

This those not happen to me,only specific customers.Browser user may not be the issue,I tried over remote conection to register and the error persists.

I know its a recaptcha issues,because in magento admin under the store configuration settings,under security I disable recaptcha for new user creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have trouble with recaptcha,one of the first things is to check the cookies.

In my case,for some reason the cookie script in my magento head html was maybe loading at a specific point in which another third party module was affecting It.

So you can try to load the script at the very end,in my case we used google tag manager to load the cookie script,the Google tag script in our case loads later on